# How to extract the pattern " [xxxxxxx] ERROR " for splunk?

Tags: regex, splunk

> 2013-11-22 08:58:43,724 **[pool-2-thread-2] ERROR**
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- The web application
>   [/probe] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-4]
>   but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory
>   leak.
>
> 2013-11-22 08:58:43,495 **[pool-2-thread-2] ERROR**
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader- The web application
>   [/ults] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value
>   [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@188bf463]) and a
>   value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value
>   [[Ljava.lang.Object;@18be8037]) but failed to remove it when the web
>   application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to
>   try and avoid a probable memory leak.

I want to extract the pattern string "[xxxxxxxxxxxxx] ERROR " , but don't know what is the rex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you need:

```
\[[^\]]*] ERROR
```

Comment: I don't know splunk, this is a regex, can you do a regex search with it?

Comment: If you want to use a regular expression, you might need to specify it for Splunk using `regex` or `rex`.

See more at http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0/SearchReference/Regex and http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0/SearchReference/Rex